# Golang interface & real type

Tags: pointers, go, interface

Let `valuePtr` and `value` be two `interface{}`. Knowing that `valuePtr` is a pointer of the type of `value`, how to make `valuePtr` points on `value`?

The "trick" I'm using currently works with the `reflect` package and a type switch:

```
switch value.(type) {
case string:
    ptr := reflect.ValueOf(valuePtr).Elem().Addr().Interface().(*string)
    *ptr = value.(string)
case ...:
    [...]
}
```

This requires one case for each type that can be given to the function. However, I am using `interface{}` to make things universal. Thus, this technic will eventually lead to a situation where dozens of types will be listed.

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
ptr := valuePtr.(*type(value))
```

Did you face this issue? What did you do?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the issue you are trying to solve using this?

Comment: Your reflect line takes an interface, dereferences it, takes the address of it, then returns the same interface you started with. I don't understand what the goal of that is supposed to be

Comment: It looks like you're trying to shoehorn in polymorphism to a language that doesn't support it, which is a bit of a code smell. Perhaps your type system isn't designed in a very go-like way?

Comment: This is typically a wrapper for a Get operation on a database. `value` is what I get from the db and `valuePtr` is given by the user. I presume the user knows the type of the value he wants.

Comment: @TimothyJones you should be right,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in the question, it looks like your goal is to set a pointer element to a value. Use this code:

```
reflect.ValueOf(valuePtr).Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/G5VlDLg3G0O)

As an aside, the code `ptr := reflect.ValueOf(valuePtr).Elem().Addr().Interface().(*string)` can be written more directly as `ptr := valuePtr.(*string)`.